# CreateMutex, OpenMutex and Process sync

Tags: c++, windows, mutex

I'm trying to do the following:

Process A should use OpenMutex to see if Process B is running.

Process B should use CreateMutex to let Process A know it's running.
Pretty simple actually...

What happens is this:

1. Run process A -> It sees that process B is not running. So far so good.
2. Run process B -> It creates the mutex.
3. Run process A again -> It sees that process B is now running. Still good.
4. I close process B (which should close the mutex as well).
5. Run process A -> It still sees that process B is running ! (OpenMutex does NOT fail).

What am I doing wrong here ??

Here is part of my code:

```
// Start of process B
HANDLE hMutex = ::CreateMutex(NULL, TRUE, MY_MUTEX_NAME);
MessageBox(NULL, _T("PROCESS B !"), _T("TEST"), 0); 
CloseHandle(hMutex);
// End of process B


// Start of process A
HANDLE hMutex = ::OpenMutex(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, MY_MUTEX_NAME);
if(hMutex != NULL)
{
   MessageBox(NULL, _T("PROCESS B is alive !"), _T("TEST"), 0); 
}
CloseHandle(hMutex);
// End of process A
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must close the mutex in process A after calling the OpenMutex to release the reference count of the mutex, so that system can delete it. Please refer [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684315%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). "The mutex object is destroyed when its last handle has been closed."

There is a working example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes but if the process which created the mutex (B in my example) exits or killed isn't the mutex supposed to be released ?

Comment: The MSDN documentation says "Use the CloseHandle function to close the handle. The system closes the handle automatically when the process terminates. The mutex object is destroyed when its last handle has been closed.". So, when the process is terminated, the handle is closed, but, not the object... this still remains..

Comment: and what about process B? You need the close handle there (naturally)... I wrote about A only because that is where it is easy to miss.